# How to Update multiple columns in this case

Tags: mysql

I have data structure as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_tax_names` (
  `sl_no` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tax_id` varchar(3) default NULL,
  `tax_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `modified_at` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`sl_no`)
) ;


INSERT INTO `admin_tax_names` (`sl_no`, `tax_id`, `tax_name`, `modified_at`) VALUES
    (1, 'T1', 'cost', '2015-01-22 16:55:19'),
    (2, 'T6', 'Service Tax', '2015-01-22 16:55:19'),
    (3, 'T3', 'VAT', '2015-01-22 16:55:19'),
    (4, 'T4', 'OtherTax2', '2015-01-22 16:55:19'),
    (5, 'T5', 'OtherTax1', '2015-01-22 16:55:20'),
    (6, 'T2', 'Discount', '2015-01-23 19:23:30'),
    (7, 'T7', 'Service Charge', '2015-02-09 20:48:19');
```

And i need to update T1 , T2 , T3 , T4, T5 , T6, T7 with different values in one statement 
I have tried as

```
UPDATE admin_tax_names SET T1 = 'cost' , T2 = 'as' , T3 = 'sas' , T4 = 'sas' , T5='sas' , T6 = 'asa' , T7 ='asas';
```

But the error i am getting is

Unknown column 'T1' in 'field list

This is my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c24d

Could you please tell me how to update table in this case ??

Comment: Check **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec4ae/1/0)** Is that what you need?

Comment: I've just upgraded [Gordon answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494179/5070879) Accept it and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you want something like this:

```
update admin_tax_names
    set tax_name = (case tax_id
                      when 'T1' then 'cost' 
                      when 'T2' then 'as' 
                      when 'T3' then 'sas'
                      when 'T4' then 'sas'
                      when 'T5' then 'sas'
                      when 'T6' then 'asa'
                      when 'T7' then 'asas'
                  end)
    where tax_id in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6', 'T7');
```

You seem to be confusing the difference between a column name and a column value.

Comment: `tax_id varchar(3) default NULL,` try to update to `'asas'` or `'cost'`

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Perhaps the intention is `tax_name`.

Comment: Probably yes, OP should clarify his question. One more thing `sl_no` is `INT` and you probably wanted `WHERE tax_id IN ...`

Comment: Thank you but when i tried to run the query i am getting syntax error .

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using a `column value` instead of column name in the update statement

[UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Here is the query;

```
UPDATE admin_tax_names 
SET `tax_name` = 
    case 
        when `tax_id` = 'T1' then 'cost' 
        when `tax_id` = 'T2' then 'as' 
        when `tax_id` = 'T3' then 'sas' 
        when `tax_id` = 'T4' then 'sas' 
        when `tax_id` = 'T5' then 'sas'
        when `tax_id` = 'T6' then 'asa'
        when `tax_id` = 'T7' then'asas'
        else `tax_name`
    end;
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e8b34/1)

Comment: You changed table structure `tax_id varchar(3) default NULL,`  in your demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dea3/1 and don't leave a note in answer

Comment: Thank you praveen , but i want to change the tax_name and keep the tax_id as it is